# Reduce camera's FPS using Android and OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, android-camera

I would like to know if there is any way to reduce the camera's fps. 
I have tried the `setPreviewFpsRange` method provided by the Android's API. The actual result of that method is usually less than the given parameter.

For example, when I `setPreviewFpsRange(15000, 15000)` (the range was taken using `getSupportedPreviewFpsRange`) the average fps is around 10 or even less when I add additional NDK functionalities. It seems that the lower bound is not followed and maybe depends on the lighting conditions.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could set using: 
    params.setPreviewFrameRate(fpsNum); //params is Camera.Parameters and fpsNum     is integer argument
Which should called before next line of code to take effect:
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
You have former line of code is in JavaCameraView.java

Also if you have performance issue, than your fps will be less then expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function setMaxFrameSize, which suggests reducing the resolution of the camera. For example, you can use it like this  `mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(640, 480);`.